# Python Pint doesn't merge units of the same quantity when multiplying

Tags: python, pint

Using Python Pint, I'm getting a strange result when multiplying units of the same quantity. You would expect them to merge, but they don't. For example:

```
from pint import UnitRegistry
units = UnitRegistry()
```

Then:

```
(3 * units.m) * ( 5 * units.m)
```

... results in:

```
<Quantity(15, 'meter ** 2')>
```

... which is correct. But if I convert one of the factors to millimeters, like so:

```
(3 * units.m) * ( 5000 * units.mm)
```

... it gives a nonsense answer:

```
<Quantity(15000, 'meter * millimeter')>
```

The same thing happens with division, and with other dimensions, like mass, time, etc.

However, addition does work:

```
(3 * units.m) + ( 5000 * units.mm)
<Quantity(8.0, 'meter')>
```

Anyone know anything about this?

Comment: The tutorial mentions `to_base_units` and `to_reduced_units` methods, maybe one of them does the convertion you need? https://pint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html

Comment: @SantiagoBruno Sure, but shouldn't this work without doing that? Notice how it does already work correctly when doing addition.

Comment: Not sure. Actually I don't use this library, just was curious about it so read some docs. It says that you can instantiate `UnitRegistry` with parameter `auto_reduce_dimensions=True`. It is disabled by default because it may be an expensive operation

Comment: @SantiagoBruno that's the answer! Thanks! Can you turn that comment into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tutorial mentions `to_base_units` and `to_reduced_units` methods, maybe one of them does the conversion you need https://pint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html

It also says that you can instantiate `UnitRegistry` with parameter `auto_reduce_dimensions=True` to have this done automatically. It is disabled by default because it may be an expensive operation

Comment: auto_reduce_dimensions=True is what I needed, thanks!